# VLAN Tag Rewriting on Juniper QFX

Tags: vlan, juniper

We have a Juniper QFX with a 10Gb port facing a 3rd party, configured as a standard trunk. Here's an example:

```
xe-0/0/1 {
    description xxxx;
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            interface-mode trunk;
            vlan {
                members [ vlan1 vlan2 ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the case above vlan1 and vlan2 are locally defined standard VLANs. The problem I have is that we use a vlan tag structure internally, and the 3rd party is not able to match it, so I'd like to rewrite their tag on ingress/egress so we can keep our internal structure. I figured this would be straightforward, but I haven't been able to make it work. I tried adding:

```
            vlan-rewrite {
                translate 2430 103;
            }
```

But it seems to have no effect. Any thoughts?

EDIT: VLAN config as requested:

```
set vlans default vlan-id 1
set vlans default l3-interface irb.0
set vlans vlan1 vlan-id 103
set vlans vlan2 vlan-id 104
```

Comment: I'm looking at this, but a couple quick questions.  1. Are these boxes in a virtual chassis?  2. Could you paste in some more of your config - "show configuration vlans | display set".

Comment: Hi Jordan, no virtual chassis, its just a standalone QFX5100. Here you go:  
`set vlans default vlan-id 1  
set vlans default l3-interface irb.0  
set vlans vlan1 vlan-id 103  
set vlans vlan2 vlan-id 104`

Comment: Facing the same issue on EX4300

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I'm currently facing the same issue and would appreciate some input :)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether that is supported or not (I suspect it does) on the QFX series--the features exists in MX series and the EX9200's and was added for QFX in 13.2+.

Per TechLibrary article [Configuring VLAN Translation with a VLAN ID List](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos15.1/topics/task/configuration/vlan-translation-vlan-id-list-l2.html), I would see if you have the `vlan-id-list` or `inner-vlan-id-list` command available, and subsititute your `vlan { members [ vlan1 vlan2 ]` with `vlan-id-list [ vlan1 vlan2 ]`.

The translation works by using the `vlan-rewrite { translate <external> <internal> }` as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Juniper Docs](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos14.1/topics/reference/configuration-statement/interface-edit-vlans-qfx-series.html)

You would do it like

> set vlans vlan1 interface xe-0/0/3.0 mapping 2430 swap

Do not confgure the vlan1 inside # edit interface xe-0/0/3.0 fam eth-sw hirachy